# Show multiple databases table in one same DataGridView in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need help with my program, my application does many things. but I am having an issue with my DataGridView it works if I only use 1 database source, but my program needs to show 3 different databases depending of the listbox user selection.

So for example if user select location1 will show location1 database table
if user chooses location2 then will show location2 database table
if the user chooses location3 then will show database table location3

Now is the same table but difference databases with different data because of difference warehouses.

so how can I accomplished this??

here is an image to where shows the user selection listbox value and datagridview will show depending of the user selection of the database the lemars21st means like location1 as a test. if you need more information please let me know.
[image]

here is part of the code is the form1 where will display as soon the application runs

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "location3")
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_FootPrint_DLDataSet.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.allInvoicesInReadyStatusTableAdapter2.Fill(this._FootPrint_DLDataSet.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus);
            }

            if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "location2")
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_FootPrint_SLDataSet.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.allInvoicesInReadyStatusTableAdapter1.Fill(this._FootPrint_SLDataSet.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus);
            }

            if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "location3")
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_FootPrint_LEMARSDataSet.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.allInvoicesInReadyStatusTableAdapter.Fill(this._FootPrint_LEMARSDataSet.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus);
            }

}
```

Comment: Can you please try this codes in combobox's SelectedIndexChanged or SelectionChanged event? If you wrote in form_load event it will be executed one time.

Comment: You are checking location3 twice! Change the bottom one to location1

Comment: yeah sorry about that, yeah I fixed the location3 having it twice, and yes I am using combobox not the listbox, but still doesn't work the way I want it.

Comment: is there a solution of my question??? each if statement will show a different database table with the same datagridview

Comment: after creating the SelectedIndexChanged event handler as you recommended fixed my issue, thanks.